# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "optionDB .txt": no such file or directory

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to open an external file which contains the styling options for the tkinter, but for some reason it is saying that the file cannot be found.

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/stjur/Desktop/STYLING.py", line 5, in <module>
    root.option_readfile('optionDB .txt')
  File "C:\Users\stjur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 871, in option_readfile
    self.tk.call('option', 'readfile', fileName, priority)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "optionDB .txt": no such file or directory
```

## my code lines:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.configure(background="#4d4d4d")#TOP LEVEL STYLING
root.option_readfile('optionDB .txt')

mytext=Text(root,background='#101010',foreground='#D6D6D6',borderwidth=18,relief='sunken',width=17,height=5)
```

I tried to research in different places for the answer, but I could not find it, could someone, please help me?

Comment: You can count on the fact that if python says it can't find a file, that file does not exist with the name you've specified. Are you aware that it will look for the file in the current working directory (ie: where you `cd` to, which may not be the same as where the script is? Also, did you intentionally put a space between "DB" and ".txt"?

Comment: it seems you start program from different folder than folder with `optionDB.txt`so it is looking for `optionDB.txt` in wrong place. 
At start you can use full path to this file `C:/full/path/optionDB.txt` to test program. Later you can find how to use `sys.argv[0]` and `os.path.realpath` to get automatically full path to folder with program and then you can use it to open `optionDB.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the problem:

```
root.option_readfile('optionDB .txt')
```

I suspect the name of the file you try to load is called `optionDB.txt` but there is a typo in your code: `optionDB .txt` (note the space before the file extension)

Apart from this, make sure your script is in the same location as the text file you try to load; if not then give the full path to it.